# MADlib apt install, how to?

Tags: postgresql, installation, shared-libraries

MADlib is the most complete, efficient (faster functions) and reliable Mathematical library for PostgreSQL... At [official download](http://madlib.incubator.apache.org/download.html)
no clues about Debian or UBUNTU "plug-and-play installation".

Checking other fonts, the best (simplest) is an old 2013's instruction for [apt-get it](http://no0p.github.io/postgresql/2013/10/27/madlib-ubuntu.html).

... Also some [lost-script](https://gist.github.com/thinkerbot/8699369#file-madlib_install-sh) of 2014... A comment say "can download the `.rpm` packages and to install in Ubuntu just convert the package to `.deb` using *Alien command* it will work".

---

Question: **secure and simplest way to install MADLib?** 
today (2017) at UBUNTU 16 LTS and PostgreSQL v9.6.

---

Note and secondary question: *Debian stable* and *UBUNTU LTS* together are the most popular Linux distributions for web-servers, so `.deb` is the most important distribution form... Why does the MADlab maintainers  refuse to see it?  Why not welcome `.deb` users?
**There are some technical or license problems with `apt` or converted `.deb` ?**

---

### EDIT

I have two types of SQL servers, the v9.6 as stated, but the most important is with *PostgreSQL v9.5.X* (!sorry we are wayting to use v9.6 in all servers).

**Situation at PostgreSQL 9.5.X in a UBUNTU 16 LTS (xenial)**

- `psql --version` and into it, `select version();`  shows *v9.5.6*.
- command `pgxnclient install madlib` shows

  ```
  You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building 
  a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
  ERROR: command returned 1: ['/usr/bin/pg_config', '--libdir']
  ```

... [pg_config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgconfig.html) is not a config file but a shell tool... So I installed it by `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` (ok!)

- command `pgxnclient install madlib` shows

  ```
    INFO: best version: madlib 1.10.0
    INFO: saving /tmp/tmpip4ngh/madlib-1.10.0.zip
    INFO: unpacking: /tmp/tmpip4ngh/madlib-1.10.0.zip
    INFO: running configure
    error: cmake 2.8 or higher must be present to configure and install MADlib
    /tmp/tmpip4ngh/madlib-1.10.0/configure: 13: exit: Illegal number: -1
    ERROR: configure failed with return code 2
  ```

... but it is not a "CMake version error", is "no CMake" error, so used `apt install cmake`!

**but** them a cmake problem,

```
pgxnclient install madlib
INFO: best version: madlib 1.10.0
INFO: saving /tmp/tmpspQ3zf/madlib-1.10.0.zip
INFO: unpacking: /tmp/tmpspQ3zf/madlib-1.10.0.zip
INFO: running configure
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find Boost
-- No sufficiently recent version (>= 1.47) of Boost was found. Will download.
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.12") 
CMake Error at src/ports/postgres/cmake/FindPostgreSQL.cmake:161 (message):
  Found pg_config ("/usr/bin/pg_config"), but pg_config.h file not present in
  the server include dir (/usr/include/postgresql/9.5/server).
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/ports/postgres/cmake/PostgreSQLUtils.cmake:66 (find_package)
  src/ports/postgres/CMakeLists.txt:360 (determine_target_versions)
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/tmpspQ3zf/madlib-1.10.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
INFO: building extension
make -C build all
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/tmpspQ3zf/madlib-1.10.0/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmpspQ3zf/madlib-1.10.0/build'
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: command returned 2: make PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config all

Comment: For MADLib install by `.rpm`  see problems at http://stackoverflow.com/q/43681870/287948

Comment: **update 2020**. Instead to use `apt`, the plug-and-play installation use `docker` and PGXN, https://hub.docker.com/r/madlib/postgres_10 and https://pgxn.org/user/madlib . All is supposed valid for pg version 10 ou greater.

Answer (score 3):

Madlib is a Postgres [extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html). Many people distribute their extensions via [pgxn.org](https://pgxn.org), which is like the [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) or [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/) of Postgres extensions. So the command to install it is this:

```
pgxnclient install madlib
```

After that, you can say `CREATE EXTENSION madlib` in whatever database you like.

Note you may need to install some dependencies first, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake postgresql-plpython-9.6 pgxnclient
```

This is what the link from 2013 is telling you, and it looks still correct to me. (Note I changed plpython from 9.1 to 9.6 though.) I tried installing madlib from pgxn myself on Postgres 9.5 + Ubuntu 14.04, and it worked.

As for why the madlib folks don't distribute a `.deb` file: you could always ask them, but pgxn is the mainstream way to share Postgres extensions. It's just like having a package manager for your programming language.

Comment: oops my PostgreSQL is 9.5,  `pgxnclient install madlib` produced "ERROR: command returned 1: ['/usr/bin/pg_config', '--libdir']"

Comment: It sounds like you don't have `pg_config` installed. I'd do `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5` then try again.

Comment: Actually it looks like `libpq-dev` and `postgresql-common` both provide `pg_config`. Maybe you can post the complete error message?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I edited the question text to show the `pgxnclient`  complete error message.

Comment: ... About CMake problem, is **reliable** and secure for UBUNTU LTS server to use [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/865294/439867)?

Comment: You don't need to build cmake yourself; the one from apt-get is fine. Your last error message (missing `pg_config.h`) suggests you need to run `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5`.

Comment: With *PostgreSQL v9.6* at fresh UBUNTU, same error: `make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: command returned 2: make PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config all`

Comment: Not make sense suggestion `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.6` (or 9.5)  after `apt install postgresql-9.6  postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6 libpq-dev postgresql-server-dev-9.6`