# pgxn install madlib UBUNTU 16 LTS not working

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, madlib

The command `pgxn install madlib`  get so many errors at *UBUNTU 16 LTS* (xenial)... There are a bug with MADLib installation for UBUNTU?

```
INFO: best version: madlib 1.10.0
INFO: saving /tmp/tmpZPEFvN/madlib-1.10.0.zip
INFO: unpacking: /tmp/tmpZPEFvN/madlib-1.10.0.zip
INFO: running configure
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    sunCC;g++

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:61 (include):
  include called with wrong number of arguments.  include() only takes one
  file.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/tmpZPEFvN/madlib-1.10.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/tmpZPEFvN/madlib-1.10.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
INFO: building extension
make -C build all
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/tmpZPEFvN/madlib-1.10.0/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/tmpZPEFvN/madlib-1.10.0/build'
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR: command returned 2: make PG_CONFIG=/usr/bin/pg_config all
```

---

See also [MADlib apt install, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43415980/287948)

Comment: Well, what is the path to your c++ compiler? Is a specific version required in madlib's documentation? It's going to be difficult to say much without at least some basic information.

Comment: @Hi @RichardHuxton thanks.  About "path to your c++ compiler", it is stadanrd UBUNTU LTS, `g++ --version` = "g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609" (2015).  `ls -lh /usr/bin/gcc`
= "/usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-5"

Comment: .. But `source g++` = "-bash: source: /usr/bin/g++: cannot execute binary file".